# "new MongoID()" throws an exception on a valid id string (PhalconPHP)

Tags: php, mongodb, cookies, phalcon

I have a function that is trying to read and decrypt a cookie (and then log the user in but that's not relevant). It breaks at the last line of below code, when trying to create MongoId of $userId:

```
public function loginWithRememberMe()
    {

        $key = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('crypt')->getKey();
        $crypt = new Phalcon\Crypt();

        $userId = $crypt->decrypt($this->cookies->get('RMU')->getValue(), $key);
        $cookieToken = $crypt->decrypt($this->cookies->get('RMT')->getValue(), $key);

        if($userId !== null && $cookieToken !== null)
        {
            $users = new User();
            $user = $users->mwFind( array( '_id' => new MongoId($userId) ) );
```

I am able to see the $userId when I run var_dump() on it, but when I try to pass it to MongoId, it fails with:

MongoException: Invalid object ID

- string itself is a valid id, as I have tested it running the query manually
- if I hardcode it inside '_id' => new MongoId(HARDCODED STRING from $userId) ), it will work fine
- function is in a library that extends Phalcon\Component
- it is called at the very beginning in my ControllerBase (base of all my controllers)
- cookies are in browser
- encryption/decryption seems to work fine (using Phalcon\Crypt)
- id in question: 4f20835f97c7142a30000c9b

Looks to me like a scope issue which I am failing to notice.

**Edit:**

mwFind is just a wrapper. Tried to run this query with "findById" and it still throws the same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was causing the error.

```
echo strlen($userId); // outputs 32 whereas it should be 24
```

There were some "invisible" characters in $userId string that would not come up even in var_dump() output.

Running:

```
$userId = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $userId);
```

resolved the issue.

Not sure if it's a Phalcon Crypt problem or if I ve missed something when it comes to handling cookies.